# Variable Lengths Differ Error on Predictive model

Tags: r

I am trying to build a predictive model from survey data. My DVs are questions on NPS and other like data points. My IVs are mainly demographical question. I keep getting a Variable lengths error using the following lines of code:

```
Model <- lm(Q6 ~ amount_spent + first_time + gender + 
                 workshop_participation + adults + children + 
                 household_adults + Below..25K. + X.25K.to..49K. + 
                 X.50K.to..74K. + X.75K.to..99K. + X.100K.to..124K. + 
                 X18.24. + X25.34. + X35.44. + X45.64.,
            data = diy_festival2)
```

**Here is the error: 
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Q6 ~ amount_spent + first_time +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Below..25K.')**

What are some possible causes and what are some potential fixes I can try?

Comment: try omitting missing values from your dataset using `na.omit()`

Comment: It's because the length of your predictor variables is not equal to the length of your target variable. If you define `y<-matrix(c(1.1,2.2))` and `x<-matrix(c(3.1,3.2,3.3))` and then try to run `lm(y~x)` you will get the same error, this is because the length of `x` is not equal to the length of `y`

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Answer (score -1):

Your formula object is referencing (a) variable(s) that is not in `diy_festival2`. It is in the global environment, the debug suggests it is `Below..25K.`

```
x <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(100))
x2 <- rnorm(10)
model.matrix( ~ x1 + x2, data=x)
```

gives the error you have.